# how to pass long value more then 65000 character in url without session

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, url, post

i want to pass long data value in next file using post method or in URL but it's say Submitted URI too large! how to solve this issue.

Comment: try it by using `POST` or even save it in the `SESSION` or `COOKIES`.

Comment: Please [follow the guidance to post a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PHP_SELF with form action to send character in length more than 65000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **$_SESSION**

> A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used
>   across multiple pages. Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored
>   on the users computer. - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Try this code using session

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    //Index Page  Storing variable 
    $_SESSION['var'] = $long_var;
?>
```

**Action.php**

```
<?php
    //Action Page Getting session 
    $long_var= $_SESSION['var'];
 ?>
```

or use method **POST**/**GET** but add hidden input field just like this.

**Index.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="long_var">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Action.php**

```
<?php 

//getting POST variable from form
$long_var = $_POST['var'];


//getting GET variable from form
$long_var = $_GET['var'];
?>
```

Comment: it is not a long variable it is long text data like 1000 lines of code that i want to pass in next page and store in to db

Comment: @JimishGajjar its still the same ? long longblob , or text, they are store in 1 variable whether they are 1000 lines then submitted by form then  run the query(insert) to save in your database

Comment: but 1000 lines code is not pass in form in post method it says it is to  large data because in post method there is limit to pass data maximum 65000 character or 1000  lines of code is more then 65000 character.

Comment: @JimishGajjar so you used, textarea and already reach the limit, check this [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24710897/Form-POST-textarea-limit.html) ,next time when you creating post read this first  [follow the guidance to post a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , many people will help you here. if you add more information on your post, including image or error codes. :) Good luck